# viewing source code in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm a newbie to learning code and I'm currently doing well learning from resources such as treehouse.

However, I would also like to learn from other developers. I have found a few sites that interest me with their build.

I wondering is there any way to view the source code as it was written.
for example when I view the source code by clicking the right mouse button then view source code it appears all on one line squashed together instead of spreading out making the code hard to read.

Here is an example of what I am talking about;
[Example of code squashed together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs7zS.png)

I wondering whether there is an add-on or plugin that will separate out 
the code into easily readable chunks so I can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click an element in the page and select "Inspect" to view the DOM as rendered - this isn't the same as the source code, but may be a better indication as (for modern sites) source may be built up by a combination of raw HTML and JS.

When you're viewing JS or CSS look for a `{}` icon in the bottom left hand corner of the panel - this will pretty print the JS while still letting you step through it.

You can use this with your CSS too:

- Go to http://solid.paris/assets/css/styles.min.1490894140.css
- Open the Chrome dev tools (CTRL+SHIFT+I)
- Click sources at the top of the tools
- Select the CSS from the left hand tree view
- Click the `{}` in the bottom left corner

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the code to this website http://jsbeautifier.org/ and 'beautify' it. There are also some addons/extentions mentioned for Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

In the dev tools window that pops up if you click the Source tab and click a file on the left then click the curly brackets at the bottom of the code window it puts it into a readable format